Powershell error but only when triggered via EEattachments?
A Powershell script which converts Excel files to CSV is triggered from a service called EEattachments. Since this morning I see errormessages in the logging of this service regarding this Powershell script:
ExportJobIntegratie:PS E C:\IICS\Scripts\ConvertExcels.ps1:The term '-or' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
When running the script on its own everything runs well and without errors but when triggered from that EEatachments service this error occurs, although the conversion is performed well.
Is there someone on this forum who can give a hint or suggestion how to solve this error?
Thanks in advance for your reaction and kind regards,
Aad

Are there any -or operations in the script split over multiple lines (eg. $false `<newline>-or $true)? Are there any -or operations at all? What's the invocation info contained in the full error message? What code do you find on that line/offset?

Do you have access to the source code of the EEattachments service? Can you [edit] the question to include an [mre]?

The issue is with the service.  What account is being used to start the servicer.  Whatever account is being used does not have permission to access the folder (or file) C:\IICS\Scripts\ConvertExcels.ps1

Thanks for your replies. Issue is solved. Still a bit confused why I couldn't reproduce the issue on another environment, but there indeed was an -or statement over multiple lines. An unintended  in a multiple -or statement was the cause .....solved it and running fine again.
